# Would a Finland prepaid SIM work in other Scandinavian countries?

Tags: cellphones, finland, scandinavia

I read from [Need fast mobile internet while in Finland for 1 month](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/21710/need-fast-mobile-internet-while-in-finland-for-1-month) that there are prepaid Finnish SIMs with data. I'm planning to go to Finland, Estonia, Sweden, Denmark and Norway.

Could someone confirm whether those SIMs would roam to other countries in Scandinavia?

From what I gathered, EU changed the roaming rules so that within it, there aren't really gigantic roaming costs anymore.

Is that the case?

Comment: Regarding "EU [...] roaming rules" they are quite well explained at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Union_roaming_regulations#Common_limits  (look at the column applying Apr 2016 to Jun 2017)

Comment: Note that nobody (at least nobody outside Estonia) considers Estonia part of Scandinavia. Hell, even Finland isn’t considered part of Scandinavia by many. [Source 1](http://satwcomic.com/how-the-north-works), [Source 2](http://satwcomic.com/party-crasher)

Comment: Good to know @Jan. I'll mind my mental shortcuts from now on ;)

Comment: I ended up eBaying a Vodafone Netherlands sim. Getting 1GB data that works in the country listed above was around 20EUR, and as long as you don't need it for more than 30 days, it wouldn't be a problem from what I could tell.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on the exact plan you get, but in general the most you should pay is about 6 cents per MB for roaming when inside the EU. Some providers may not let you roam on a prepaid plan so it's best to ask when you buy the SIM card.

Some providers may provide free roaming within the EU or the Nordics/Baltics. For example Sonera have a data plan for €24.90 for a month which lets you use the data in the Nordics and Baltics. You might be able to find a similar option for prepaid plans.

https://www.sonera.fi/kauppa/liittymat/nettiliittymat/prepaid-netti
https://www.sonera.fi/dam/jcr:15386e12-dad3-4397-836c-44c919d73860/Sonera%20Wireless%20Surf%20Service%20Description.pdf

Comment: The data plan you are linking to is subscription/invoice based and not prepaid. I doubt that it is available to persons not resident in Finland.